# In Google Cloud Build, what is the difference between an array of args and a long string as an arg?

Tags: google-cloud-build

While setting up a my build system to automatically version my containers in Cloud Registry ([How do I set an environment or substitution variable via a step in Google Cloud Build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52337831/how-do-i-set-an-environment-or-substitution-variable-via-a-step-in-google-cloud/52416104#52416104)), I ran into a frustrating error.

This works:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'docker build -t gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$SHORT_SHA -t gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:latest -t gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$(cat VERSION) -t gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$(cat SEMVER) -t gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$(cat MAJOR) -t gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$(cat MAJOR).$(cat MINOR) .']
images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME']
```

But this does not work:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'docker', 'build',
    '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$SHORT_SHA',
    '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:latest',
    '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$(cat VERSION)',
    '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$(cat SEMVER)',
    '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$(cat MAJOR)',
    '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$(cat MAJOR).$(cat MINOR)',
    '.']
images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME']
```

Shouldn't these be equivalent? What am  I missing?

Comment: In your post, you said "this does not work" ... can you elaborate on the error seen?

Comment: @Kolban It outputs the docker usage
"Usage: docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

````
```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: 
      - -c
      - |
        docker build -t gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$SHORT_SHA \
        -t gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:latest \
        -t gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$(cat VERSION) \
        -t gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$(cat SEMVER) \
        -t gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$(cat MAJOR) \
        -t gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$(cat MAJOR).$(cat MINOR) .

images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME']
```
````

and one way this could work is. Just removing the entry point from bash.

````
```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build',
    '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$SHORT_SHA',
    '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:latest',
    '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$(cat VERSION)',
    '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$(cat SEMVER)',
    '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$(cat MAJOR)',
    '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$(cat MAJOR).$(cat MINOR)',
    '.']
images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME']
```
````

Comment: to be exactly answer your question, your entry point is bash. 

executing docker build -t <blah> . is different from docker , build, -t <blah> , .